# non static not called statically

Tags: php, static, call

How can I call the method dynamically?
I've called the function:

```
    public function type_bien($value)
    {
        $stype['1'] = "Maison";
        $stype['2'] = "Appartement";
        $stype['4'] = "Appartement meubl&eacute;";
        $stype['7'] = "Propri&eacute;t&eacute;";
        return $stype[$value];
    }

<?php echo type_bien($row['type_bien']); ?>

-> Returns: Deprecated: Non-static method Utils::type_bien() should not be called statically
```

Comment: You are returning something, so you should call the function like this: `<?php $myResult = type_bien($row['type_bien']); echo $myResult; ?>`

Comment: Can you please be more specific as to why you're declaring it as a public function without it being wrapped in a class? Is it meant to be a function or a class method?

Comment: Emn1ty->
this is actually a class:

Comment: class Utils
{
    public function type_bien($value)
    {
        $stype['1'] = "Maison";
        $stype['2'] = "Appartement";
        $stype['4'] = "Appartement meubl&eacute;";
        $stype['7'] = "Propri&eacute;t&eacute;";
        return $stype[$value];
    }
}

Comment: when I call:
<?php $myResult = type_bien($row['type_bien']); echo $myResult; ?>

Comment: -> undefined function

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call a method dynamically, check this example:

```
<?php

Class Demo {
    public function test () {
      echo "OK";
    }
}

$demo_1= new Demo();
$dynamic = "test";

$demo_1->{$dynamic}();

// i.e. $demo_1->test();
// prints OK

// or

Demo::{$dynamic}();
// i.e. Demo::test();
// prints OK

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a object of the class Utils

```
class Utils {
 public function type_bien($value) {
    $stype['1'] = "Maison";
    $stype['2'] = "Appartement";
    $stype['4'] = "Appartement meubl&eacute;";
    $stype['7'] = "Propri&eacute;t&eacute;";
    return $stype[$value];
 }
}

$utils = new Utils();
echo $utils->type_bien($row['type_bien']);
```

or you can just define the method as static function

```
class Utils {
 public static function type_bien($value) {
    $stype['1'] = "Maison";
    $stype['2'] = "Appartement";
    $stype['4'] = "Appartement meubl&eacute;";
    $stype['7'] = "Propri&eacute;t&eacute;";
    return $stype[$value];
 }
}

echo Utils::type_bien($row['type_bien']);
```

Comment: ok, works fine. I understand better now. Thank you so much for your time. I appreciate it.